# CSS display table doesn't respect fixed height

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS layout which is necessary, cannot be changed so it preserves its middle centring.

Div `display:table` (height defined) with one div inside `display:table-cell`, both `vertical-align:middle;` (I use that for vertically centring of the content). The problem is that when the content overflows the defined height, it simply overflows the table, making it bigger.

I need to set something like `overflow:hidden` which doesn't seem to work with tables... I just need to hide the overflowing content or better, add scrollbar to table. Is there a way?

CSS

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
.table {
  float:left;
  margin: 10px;
  display:table;
  height:500px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:#ccc;
}
.table-cell {
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">
    some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">
    some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lytea

Comment: is this an option for you? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dFLrk

Comment: No, I need the table to have defined height, eg. 500px in my example. But as you can see, the second table just grew over 500px, instead of scrollbar being added...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987114/display-table-height-not-always-respected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to wrap your content with a inline-block level element with max-height 100%,
and, you need to set `height: inherit` on the `table-cell` elements.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
.table {
  float:left;
  margin: 10px;
  display:table;
  height:500px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:#ccc;
}
.table-cell {
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:table-cell;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <div class="wrapper">
    some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <div class="wrapper">
    some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>some tall content
    <br>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but it wants his content vertical aligned center.

Comment: Yes, this is almost the desired effect however it breaks the vertical alignment which is the main purpose of using tables.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` in your `.table-cell` like this

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: auto;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

please try the above css

P.S. to get the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` it require the `white-space` and the `overflow` properties.

`overflow` can be either `auto` or `scroll` or `hidden`.

Comment: Either I made some mistake or it doesn't work. Can you post jsfiddle or codepen with example? As you can see here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aFCGf the second table is still over defined 500px

Comment: the 2nd table is the one on the right side, is that right?

Comment: sure, I was counting it like second in the code – the one on the right ;)

Comment: great then, I believe that the cell height is 500px.. please change the height to `height:200px;` and you will see that both cell height has been changed to 200px and both has a scroll.

Comment: but the height can vary so I don't see a point in changing it to 200px. BTW when I change it to 200px it still overflows (Chrome latest here)