# display table height not always respected

Tags: html, css

I have the code below. For some reason when the table height is smaller than the height of the cells, the height is not respected. Why is that?

```css
.table {
        border: 1px solid red;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: table;
        height: 15px;
      }
      .cell {
        height: inherit;
        border-width: 0;
        display: table-cell;
      }
      .cell span {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 31px;
      }
```

```html
    <body>
      <div class="table">
        <span class="cell">
          <span>test1</span>
        </span>
        <span class="cell">
          <span>test2</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table cell and table heights are only initial recommendations. The same thing to a degree happens with width. If the content of the words can't shrink any further in width the table will grow to fit.

Think of it as a min-height when used on table styled elements.

If you are wanting the content inside to have a maximum height you will want to set the height and overflow, etc. on the final child span inside.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're emulating a table using `<div>` and `<span>` elements you're inheriting some browser CSS styles, namely `line-height`.

Define a `font-size` equal to the height of the table, then set the `line-height` of the child elements to `1em`.

```css
.table {
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table;
    height: 15px;
  }
  .cell {
    height: inherit;
    border-width: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 15px;
  }
  .cell span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 31px;
    line-height: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <span class="cell">
      <span>test1</span>
    </span>
    <span class="cell">
      <span>test2</span>
    </span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: table` works the same way as the `<table>` element.

The `height` of a `<table>` is determined by the `height` of its cells.

If you were to change `.table`'s `display` attribute to `block`, `.table`'s height would take effect.

```css
.table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
}
.cell {
  height: 75px;
  border-width: 0;
  display: table-cell;
}
.cell span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <span class="cell">
      <span>test1</span>
  </span>
  <span class="cell">
      <span>test2</span>
  </span>
</div>
```