# table don't respond to css properties

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created an html table and I am trying to set a `max-height` and `height` properties to it
but the table don't accept them
I am using this code
**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="Table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 0 0</td>
            <td>Row 0 1</td>
            <td>Row 0 2</td>
            <td><a id="table-buttons" class="btn btn-primary">Row 0 3</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 0</td>
            <td>Row 1 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 2</td>
            <td><a id="table-buttons" class="btn btn-primary">Row 1 3</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 0</td>
            <td>Row 2 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 2</td>
            <td><a id="table-buttons" class="btn btn-primary">Row 2 3</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#Table {
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 210px;
    max-height: 210px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

td {
    width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

the table:
[image]

The specified `height` and `max-height`
mustn't allow the table to carry more than these three rows and the header
but when I add another row the table 
totally ignores the `height` and the `max-height`
and expands to fit the four rows

I want the table to show a scrollbar as a result of the `overflow-y: auto` property
but the didn't happen

I am using This [Bootstrap](https://bootswatch.com/paper/) style

please help

Comment: How are you including your CSS?

Comment: Yes I included it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting table height is overruled by the table content. See this answer: [display table height not always respected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987114/display-table-height-not-always-respected)

You could work around it by wrapping a div around it (and setting the height and overflow on the div).

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/a/36987513/8058050 answer worked for me

Comment: @O.Shehab You could up-vote that answer as well then, since you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Put the table in a div, and set the height and width for that div:

```
<div id="Table">
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <!-- Table rows and data -->
   </table>
</div>
```

Note: remove the id from the table tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap a `div` around the `table`, checkout this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/DavidGenger/pen/BwyajZ?editors=1100) for a demo

Answer (score -3):

You should target the class, not the ID.

Like this:

```
.table {
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 210px;
    max-height: 210px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why would that matter?

Comment: that is not true

Comment: Well, it works for me?  The height was respected when I changed it from the id name to the class name

Comment: No I targeted the ID in another list and it worked

Comment: Well, in this case, if you change it to the class, it works